# Generating CRC32 checksum in c# with input string

Tags: c#, checksum, crc32

I'm trying to generate a CRC32 checksum for the Kraken exchange's orderbooks as described [here](https://docs.kraken.com/websockets/#book-checksum). I found another post in SO that referenced [this Github file](https://github.com/force-net/Crc32.NET/blob/develop/Crc32.NET/Crc32Algorithm.cs) in order to generate the CRC32 checksum. The issue I have is that I need to generate the checksum based off an input `string`, where all of the checksum functions I've found take a `byte[]` as an input.

I tried converting the `string` to a `byte[]`, but it doesn't give me the expected result that I should be getting as per the Kraken docs.

```cs
string inputString = "50055005010500501550050205005025500503050050355005040500504550050505005000500499550049905004980500497550049705004965500496050049555004950500";
        
Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
var byteArr = crc32.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString));
    
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArr));
```

The value this logs will be `":??"`, where as I'm supposed to be getting `"974947235"`.

Clearly, I must be doing something completely wrong here. What am I missing?

Comment: The code looks correct, so I guess there could be a problem in constructing the input string (you may need to checksum something else) or you're using the wrong encoding to get the `byte[]`. You'll need to find the relevant documentation for these two pieces of information.

Comment: You need to use ToString() : Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", byteArr.Select(x => x.ToString("2X"))));

Comment: [CRC32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#CRC-32_algorithm) is 4 bytes, I wonder what is `"974947235"`? Is it 97, 49, 47, 235 base10 values of 4 bytes or what is it?

Comment: @jdweng `byte[]` doesn't have a member `.Select()`

Comment: The GITHUB link doesn't have a ComputeHash method, and is returning an int.  So you can try : ConsoleWriteline(byteArray.ToString("8X");

Answer (score 1):

`ComputeHash` returns `byte[]`, so you will get four bytes back. Your `974947235` becomes in hex `3a, 1c, 83, a3`. Or `58, 28, 131, 163` in decimal. Trying to print random bytes as characters can only lead to angst and frustration. Print them as numbers. Note that 58 is the colon (":") character, so in fact your first character is correct.

By the way, there are many CRC-32's, but you seem to have stumbled on to the correct one, as the string you provided does indeed result in the [CRC-32/ISO-HDLC](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm#crc.cat.crc-32-iso-hdlc): `974947235`.

Comment: OK, so I'm now getting `3a, 1c, 83, a3` by using `BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArr)`, and I can get `5828131163` by using `Convert.ToInt32(s, 16)` on each `s` in the `hex.split('-')` fo the hex above, but how do I get to `97497235`?

Answer (score 1):

[Mark's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64397078/3478500) got me half way there. The solution I found was to convert to a hex, and then convert that hex into an `int`, like so:

```cs
Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
byte[] byteArr = crc32.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));

string hex = BitConverter.ToString(byteArr);

int desiredInt = int.Parse(
   hex.Replace("-", string.Empty),
   System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: Well that's a roundabout way of doing it. If you want the integer value, just add up the byte values as digits. E.g. `((uint)byteArr[0] << 24) + ((uint)byteArr[1] << 16) + ((uint)byteArr[2] << 8) + byteArr[3]`.